# Dynamic render UI input and output R shiny

Tags: shiny

**EDITE :**
I added one more example that is same as my problem. I want to update the `checkboxGroupInput` as `dataset` changes. And also want to render the table with checked column in the `checkboxGroupInput` options.

**SERVER**

```
shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

    dataset_list <- list( "rock" = rock,    
                          "pressure" = pressure,
                          "cars" = cars
                         )

    observeEvent( input$n_select_input, {

         selected_dataset <- reactive({ 
                                 selected_list <- list()
                                 for( i in 1:input$n_select_input ){
                                       selected_list[[i]] <- dataset_list[[i]]
                                  }
                                 names(selected_list) <- names( dataset_list )[1:input$n_select_input]
                                 selected_list
                              })


        colname_indata_list <- reactive({

                                 colname.indata.list <- list()
                                 for( set in names( selected_dataset() ) ){
                                     colname.indata.list[[set]] <- colnames( selected_dataset()[[set]] )
                                     }
                                 colname.indata.list
                                 })


        choice_cand <- reactive({ names(selected_dataset()) })


    updateSelectInput( session,
                       "dataset",
                       choices = as.character( choice_cand() )
                      )

    choices_cand <- reactive({ colname_indata_list()[[input$dataset]] })

    updateCheckboxGroupInput( session, 
                              "column",
                              choices = as.character( choices_cand() ) 
                             )

  })


# observeEvent( input$dataset, {
#   
#   choices_cand <- reactive({ colname_indata_list()[[input$dataset]] })
#   updateCheckboxGroupInput( session, "column",
#                             choices = as.character( choices_cand() ) )
#   
# })

datasetInput <- reactive({
  switch(input$dataset,
         "rock" = rock,
         "pressure" = pressure,
         "cars" = cars)
  })

output$table <- renderTable({
  datasetInput()
  })


} )
```

I tried the code above in the ## , it didn't work.

**UI**

```
shinyUI( 
  fluidPage( titlePanel('Downloading Data'),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel( numericInput( "n_select_input", "n select inpur", 1,
                                           min=1, max=3 ),
                              selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
                                         choices = "" ),
                             checkboxGroupInput( "column", "select column",
                                                 choices = "")
                             ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput('table')
                 )
               )
             )
  )
```

**FIRST WRITE :**

I simplified the code below. I want to use updated select input as a output for the updatedCheckboxGroupInput 's choices. But the updated select input, `input$select_group` is null. I tried varies solutions.. but couldn't solve it.
If you just run this code right away, it doesn't work..

```
fund_group <- reactive({ # this is the list of fund group including fund name
                         # for example,
                         "domestic" = c("a","b", "c"),
                         "global" = c( "aa", "bb", "cc")
                         # list name and fund name in the list are changable
                       })
```

I want to update `selectInput` choices as `names(fund_group)` changes.
So I used code below,

```
observe({
         group_name <- reactive({ names(fund_group()) })
         updateSelectInput( session,
                            "select_group",
                            choices = group_name() )

         fund_list <- reactive({ fund_group()[[input$select_group]] })
         updateCheckboxGroupInput( session,
                                   "fund_in_group",
                                   choices = fund_list(),
                                   selected = fund_list() )
        })
```

For the  UI,

```
narvarPage( "narvarTitle",
tabPanel( "tab panel",

fluidRow( column( 3, wellPanel( textOutput( "fixed_anal_date" ),
          br(),
          br(),
          selectInput( "select_group",
                       label = "Select group",
                       choices = "" ),
          br(),
          checkboxGroupInput( "fund_in_group",
                              label = "Select funds :",
                              choices = "" ),
          br()
  ) )
) )
```

Thank you for reading the messy code...

Comment: Can you explain your problem better and post a minimal reproducible example? This one has missing functions.

Comment: @BárbaraBorges I edited my code, thank  you for the reply! hope it would be better to recognize

Comment: This code still seems to have some missing function

Comment: @SBista I edited whole code... hope it can help you understand what I meant

Comment: @yeyoung Now I understand what you mean. I'll look into this later tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the code an its working now. You should put the two input in two different observe.

Here is the server. R:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  fund_group <- reactive({ # this is the list of fund group including fund name
    # for example,
    list("domestic" = c("a","b", "c"),  "global" = c( "aa", "bb", "cc"))
    # list name and fund name in the list are changable
  })

  observe({
    group_name <- reactive({ names(fund_group()) })
    updateSelectInput( session,
                       "select_group",
                       choices = group_name() )

  })

  observe({
    fund_list <- reactive({ fund_group()[[input$select_group]] })
    updateCheckboxGroupInput( session,
                              "fund_in_group",
                              choices = fund_list(),
                              selected = fund_list())
  })

}
```

Here is the ui.R:

```
ui <- navbarPage( "narvarTitle",
            tabPanel( "tab panel",

                      fluidRow( column( 3, wellPanel( textOutput( "fixed_anual_date" ),
                                                      br(),
                                                      br(),
                                                      selectInput( "select_group",
                                                                   label = "Select group",
                                                                   choices = "" ),
                                                      br(),
                                                      checkboxGroupInput( "fund_in_group",
                                                                          label = "Select funds :",
                                                                          choices = "" ),
                                                      br()
                      ) )
                      ) )

)
```

**[EDIT]:**

As per your latest update I have modified the server code so that `checkboxGrouptInput` is updated as `dataset` changes and also the table is rendered for the checked columns.

```
shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

  dataset_list <- list( "rock" = rock,    
                        "pressure" = pressure,
                        "cars" = cars
  )

  observeEvent( input$n_select_input, {

    selected_dataset <- reactive({ 
      selected_list <- list()
      for( i in 1:input$n_select_input ){
        selected_list[[i]] <- dataset_list[[i]]
      }

      names(selected_list) <- names( dataset_list )[1:input$n_select_input]
      selected_list
    })


    colname_indata_list <- reactive({

      colname.indata.list <- list()
      for( set in names( selected_dataset() ) ){
        colname.indata.list[[set]] <- colnames( selected_dataset()[[set]] )
      }

      colname.indata.list
    })


    choice_cand <- reactive({ 
      names(selected_dataset()) })

    updateSelectInput( session,
                       "dataset",
                       choices = as.character( choice_cand() )
    )

    ######################################Start: Modified#############################

    observe({

      input$dataset  ##Added so that this observe is called when the input$dataset changes
      choices_cand <- reactive({ 

        colname_indata_list()[[input$dataset]] })

      updateCheckboxGroupInput( session, 
                                "column",
                                choices = as.character( choices_cand()) ,
                                selected = as.character( choices_cand())
      )

    })

    })

  ######################################End: Modified#############################


  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()[,input$column]##only selected columns are displayed
  })


} )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the answer.  I tried this already.. but didn't work :(

Comment: @김예영 It seems to work for me! Here is a working [demo](https://sbista.shinyapps.io/Demo-SO40341423/).

Comment: Does it works even if the selected group choices are reactive values??

Comment: In my code, `fund_group` is changeable along with another input data. so I used reactive function for the `fund_group`.

Comment: @yeyoung I have edited the answer as per your updated example. Hope it helps!